# avconv throwing errors while converting mov to ogg

Tags: codec

I am getting the following error constantly while trying to convert mov file to ogg using avconv and ffmpeg. I am completely unable to understand the verbose messages displayed below.

I looked at similar threads, but could not make out anything from it. Does anyone have any ideas?

- [Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:1 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8367342/error-while-opening-encoder-for-output-stream-01-maybe-incorrect-parameters)
- [ffmpeg error while converting to mp4 Error while opening encoder for output stream #0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12847980/ffmpeg-error-while-converting-to-mp4-error-while-opening-encoder-for-output-stre)
- http://drupal.org/node/1779298

```
 
    parth@parth-laptop:~/Desktop$ avconv -i IMG_0243.mp4 -acodec vorbis -f ogg IMG_0243.ogv 
    avconv version 0.8.3-4:0.8.3-0ubuntu0.12.04.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2012 the Libav developers
      built on Jun 12 2012 16:37:58 with gcc 4.6.3
    Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'IMG_0243.mp4':
      Metadata:
        major_brand     : qt  
        minor_version   : 0
        compatible_brands: qt  
        creation_time   : 2012-02-25 00:11:52
        encoder         : 5.0.1
        encoder-eng     : 5.0.1
        date            : 2012-02-24T16:11:52-0800
        date-eng        : 2012-02-24T16:11:52-0800
      Duration: 00:00:34.59, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 24121 kb/s
        Stream #0.0(und): Video: h264 (Baseline), yuv420p, 1920x1080, 24069 kb/s, 24.01 fps, 24 tbr, 600 tbn, 1200 tbc
        Metadata:
          creation_time   : 2012-02-25 00:11:52
        Stream #0.1(und): Audio: aac, 44100 Hz, mono, s16, 62 kb/s
        Metadata:
          creation_time   : 2012-02-25 00:11:52
    File 'IMG_0243.ogv' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
    [buffer @ 0x8da9ce0] w:1920 h:1080 pixfmt:yuv420p
    [vorbis @ 0x8dc74e0] Current Libav Vorbis encoder only supports 2 channels.
    Output #0, ogg, to 'IMG_0243.ogv':
      Metadata:
        major_brand     : qt  
        minor_version   : 0
        compatible_brands: qt  
        creation_time   : 2012-02-25 00:11:52
        encoder         : 5.0.1
        encoder-eng     : 5.0.1
        date            : 2012-02-24T16:11:52-0800
        date-eng        : 2012-02-24T16:11:52-0800
        Stream #0.0(und): Video: libtheora, yuv420p, 1920x1080, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 90k tbn, 24 tbc
        Metadata:
          creation_time   : 2012-02-25 00:11:52
        Stream #0.1(und): Audio: libvorbis, 44100 Hz, mono, s16, 200 kb/s
        Metadata:
          creation_time   : 2012-02-25 00:11:52
    Stream mapping:
      Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 -> libtheora)
      Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac -> vorbis)
    Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:1 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
```

edit:

I actually got it to work...but now cannot get an FPS of more than 8 for some reason.

the command that worked was

```
avconv -i IMG_0243.mp4 -acodec libvorbis -f ogg -r 24.01 IMG_0243.ogv -ac 2 -ar 44100 -b 64k -s 1920x1080
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about the fps printed on the screen that is just the rate of encoding. It has nothing to do with the fps of the file that will be created. Encoding a 1080p requires high end hardware and fast encoders. While you may have the hardware libtheora is not optimized like other encoders. So it will be slow.